# Prisoner Role, Discord.py 1.5.0a

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to do a bot that picks up all roles from user, send a message that mention all roles in a channel, so the bot need remove all roles and add a 'Prisoner' role and send a reason for the prison. How do I do this?
I'm trying to do this command for 3 days, but nobody could help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for deleting all roles and adding prisoner role:

```py
@client.command()
async def prison(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    member_roles = []
    for role in member.roles:
        member_roles.append(role) 
        await member.remove_roles(role)
    member_roles = ', '.join(member_roles) 
    await ctx.send(f'{member.mention} is in prison. His {member_roles} roles are deleted.')
    prisoner = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='Prisoner')
    await member.add_roles(prisoner)
```

After you create the **Prisoner** role, change the permissions of this role for all the channels except for **Prison** channel in Discord.

**Note**: There could be syntax problems in my code because I'm on mobile right now. If any problem raises, just comment.